# Does the Facebook Comments Social Plugin have an API where comments can be added?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, comments, facebook-comments

Once the Facebook Comments Plugin is installed on a site, can comments be added and removed  programatically via the Graph (or other) API? For example, if a publisher (using their FB profile) would like to seed commentary.

Comment: @RobertHarvey All methods of post can be misused as spam or fishing, Facebook gives all developers more than enough rope to hang them selves, pretty much up to the developer to choose the dark side lol.

Comment: No plans on outright spamming our own commentary, but would like to see how to nudge the discussion along with comment-like info we have available. Let's call it the "gray side".

Answer (score 2):

The answer is NO, this is not possible, by design.

Using the [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), you can test the API calls detailed for Comments objects [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-comments/#creating):

```
POST {object_id}/comments?message='graph-test-1'
```

...which (assuming you have a properly configured Comment plugin) results in this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Comments may not be added to a comment plugin", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In theory, all comments made through the plugin have id's which can be accessed via the graph api.

For example: https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments

&&

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/Comment/

Posting like or comment to that id should generate a comment in that array.  I have never done this, but i will give it shot and post back with any sample code i can get working.  "via PHP SDK 3.1.1"

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I am attempting the same thing but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

the facebook's graph API may not be used to add comments to a comment plugin, only comment social plugin of web version can do it.